# Making a Stacked Bar Chart Out of Table Columns in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, charts, statistics

I'm trying to create a stacked bar graph showing body composition. I have a table/data set (I don't know the correct term) that looks like this:

```
structure(list(data.Date = structure(1:7, .Label = c("2021-03-06", 
"2021-03-07", "2021-03-08", "2021-03-09", "2021-03-10", "2021-03-11", 
"2021-03-12"), class = "factor"), total_bf = c(19.6612, 18.2182, 
19.6803, 21.7047, 18.126, 19.7, 19.1424), total_muscle = c(41.5948, 
43.043, 42.1578, 42.1866, 43.4017, 42.2, 42.2728), other = c(37.544, 
38.8388, 38.0619, 38.0087, 39.1723, 38.1, 38.2848)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Each column is a weight in kilograms. Together they add up to the total body weight of the subject. What I want is a stacked bar graph where each bar represents a date and each bar is split by total_bf, total_muscle and other. All of the guides and Q&As I've seen don't seem to apply to my situation. Maybe this is because I am new but nothing I've tried has worked yet.

An example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

The only difference is that on my graph blue would be body fat (total_bf), green would be other and red would be muscle (total_muscle).

Comment: You'd have to convert from wide data format to long data format, giving each measurement a seperate row along with IDs. Also, please don't [include data or code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11374827).

Comment: Could you tell me how to get a similar looking table in a text format? I tried table() but the output was nonsensical

Comment: An easy way to share data on SO for R question is by using `dput(your_data_frame)` and copy-pasting the output of that call to your question. It looks ugly, but people looking to give an answer can just copy-paste it from your question directly into our R session and have the same data as you do.

Comment: No kidding, quite the eyesore. Is it good practice to keep the image alongside the dput() output or should I delete it entirely?

Comment: The image of the data is pretty useless other than getting a glimpse of the data structure (no offence intended). If people want a prettily formatted table, they can always copy-paste the dput output into their own R sessions and look at the table there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert data from the wide format to the long format using `tidyr::pivot_longer()` function:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- structure(list(
  data.Date = structure(
    1:7, 
    .Label = c("2021-03-06", "2021-03-07", "2021-03-08", "2021-03-09", 
               "2021-03-10", "2021-03-11", "2021-03-12"), class = "factor"), 
  total_bf = c(19.6612, 18.2182, 19.6803, 21.7047, 18.126, 19.7, 19.1424), 
  total_muscle = c(41.5948, 43.043, 42.1578, 42.1866, 43.4017, 42.2, 42.2728), 
  other = c(37.544, 38.8388, 38.0619, 38.0087, 39.1723, 38.1, 38.2848)
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df, -data.Date)
```

Then using ggplot2, the defaults already make a stacked bar chart, so you just need to specify `x`, `y` and `fill` aesthetics.

```r
ggplot(long, aes(data.Date, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Since your date is encoded as a factor, if you want to encode it as a real date you can convert it as follows:

```r
long$date <- as.Date(strptime(as.character(long$data.Date), format = "%Y-%m-%d"))

ggplot(long, aes(date, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>